# Installing Direct X 11 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine, games, steam, macbook

I'm trying to play Dragon Quest 11 on Ubuntu using Proton DB 5.13.6.  The game keeps coming up saying Direct X 11 is required.  I'm playing it on a Macbook Pro 2012 with the following specs:

Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz x 4

Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

64-bit

I tried installing wine but it kept saying something about gecko, which I tried to research but didn't understand.

I found a post saying that I need a Vulkan drive, but that Vulkan doesn't run on a Macbook pro that so old.  Is there anyway to install Direct X 11 or any work-arounds?

Comment: DirectX is for Windows software.  Does this game have a native linux client?

Comment: Steam uses proton for cross platform support.  It works on a new Macbook pro 2015 that I have but unfortunately I can't install the game on that machine.  That makes me wonder if it's a issue with the processor or graphics card being too old.

Comment: Windows or Linux is irrelevant, I play Windows games on Wine all the time without loss of performance. People should be more careful before commenting on things they don't have direct experience with, spreading false myths around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Wine ever successfully supported DirectX 11. I think it was never finished. More recently people that have been using Vulkan are reporting even better framerates than using Wine's native DirectX 9.
I don't recall the entire installation procedure. You will need to obtain the latest winetricks from GitHub, then:

```
chmod +x /path/winetricks
<optional> sudo ln -s /path/winetricks /usr/bin
```

And then:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_test64 WINEARCH=win64 winecfg
< the above will create your initial wine prefix >
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_test64 WINEARCH=win64 winetricks
< pick "Select Default Wine Prefix" and pick "Install DLL's or Windows components", search for dxvulkan or dvkd3d >
< to avoid having to write all that big command everytime
you can simply rename ~/.wine_test64 to ~/.wine
and then you will be able to type only winetricks when needed.
That's the default location of wine. >
```

I never used Vulkan, but if I'm not mistaken you will also need to install the i386 versions of your graphics drivers, penGL libraries, Vulkan libraries, etc.

Verify which ones you are missing using these commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep glx
dpkg -l | grep gl1
dpkg -l | grep mesa
dpkg -l | grep vk    < that's an L, not an I, it's for List >
```

Comment: I tried some of the steps but it looks like my computer is just too old.  Thanks for the shot though!

Comment: Most games provide a way to revert back to Direct X 9 (d3d9) Most times, all you have to do is delete or rename the d3d11 DLL file in the game's directory. Have you tried that? Only leave the d3d9 file there, and the game should pick it up at startup. Other games require you to run it from command line adding parameters such as -d3d9 to the end of the command line

Comment: Another problem that might happen sometimes (and this happened to me a few months back) is that sometimes Wine installation becomes confused and the video drivers are not installed, or they are installed only for 32-bit Wine, or other times they only work in 64-bit Wine for don't work for 32-bit applications. In this case, I had to reinstall one of the wine packages, the amd64 one, and that fixed the problem for me. Other time, I had to install i386 video drivers as described at the end of my answer above, the ones ending in glx or mesa, that fixed it to play older 32-bit 3D games.

Answer (score 0):

He probably isn't here `/usr/lib/`.
Like on my device.

```
ldconfig -p | grep vulkan
    libvulkan_radeon.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
    libvulkan_radeon.so (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
    libvulkan_intel.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
    libvulkan_intel.so (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
    libvulkan.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
    libvulkan.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
    libvulkan.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so
```

```
ldd `which vulkaninfo`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3cdd4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7490a6f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f7490a45000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f7490908000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f74908f7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7490716000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f74906fb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7490507000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7490b20000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f7490501000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f74904f9000)
    libffi.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f74904ed000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f74904ca000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f749037b000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f749035f000)
```

```
ldd /usr/lib/libvulkan.so.1*
ldd: /usr/lib/libvulkan.so.1*: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

```
vulkaninfo
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
INTEL-MESA: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
```

```
root@Venue-11-Pro-7130-vPro:/home/mct# sudo dpkg -l | grep glx
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                         20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libglx-mesa0:i386                          20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libglx0:amd64                              1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLX support
ii  libglx0:i386                               1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- GLX support
ii  libxcb-glx0:amd64                          1.14-2                                amd64        X C Binding, glx extension
ii  libxcb-glx0:i386                           1.14-2                                i386         X C Binding, glx extension
root@Venue-11-Pro-7130-vPro:/home/mct# sudo dpkg -l | grep gl1
ii  libegl1:amd64                              1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- EGL support
ii  libgl1:amd64                               1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- legacy GL support
ii  libgl1:i386                                1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- legacy GL support
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                       20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64                 1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer GL libraries
ii  libwayland-egl1:amd64                      1.18.0-1                              amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - EGL library
ii  libwayland-egl1:i386                       1.18.0-1                              i386         wayland compositor infrastructure - EGL library
root@Venue-11-Pro-7130-vPro:/home/mct# sudo dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl-mesa0:amd64                         20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                       20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                        20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglapi-mesa:i386                         20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                         9.0.1-1build1                         amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa:i386                          9.0.1-1build1                         i386         Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                         20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libglx-mesa0:i386                          20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libosmesa6:i386                            20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  mesa-utils                                 8.4.0-1build1                         amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
ii  mesa-va-drivers:amd64                      20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-va-drivers:i386                       20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64                   20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386                    20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64                  20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386                   20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
root@Venue-11-Pro-7130-vPro:/home/mct# sudo dpkg -l | grep vk
ii  libvkd3d1:i386                             1.1-4                                 i386         Direct3D 12 to Vulkan translation - library
ii  lunarg-vkconfig                            1.2.170.0~rc2-1lunarg20.04-1          amd64        LunarG GUI tool to configure Vulkan layers
```

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

VULKAN_SDK=~/Downloads/VulkanSDK/1.2.170/x86_64
PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
```

```
{
    "ICD": {
        "api_version": "1.2.170",
        "library_path": "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so"
    },
    "file_format_version": "1.0.0"
}
```

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4200 (HSW GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Try  PlayOnlinux.
I haven't tried the games, but it seems to me that it has all the tools for this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for following up.  I tried to install vulkan but it looks like my computer's too old.  I tried playonlinux but it kept giving me error messages.  Your answer was helpful though, thanks!